# socket.timeout: timed out Error in pyzk library

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, fingerprint

When trying to connect fingerprint machine through LAN. I used Python with pyzk library. It is successfully connected. But when trying to get users data and attendances data, it is shown as **socket.timeout: timed out** error as following image.

[image]

Comment: "Connection successful" and "Session is opened"  is different. No answer maybe an "reject method".

Comment: It can retrieve attendance data in small amount of sign in/out. But when I connect with fingerprint that stores huge data. It's take too long ridiculously and fail.

Comment: `from pyzk import ZK ; my_ZK = ZK(IP,PORT,timeout)` . Timeout default value is `60` change to big value, another issue is `permission` or `additional module`

Comment: Already changed to none for timeout. It's took 4 or 5 hours and timed out. For small amount of attendance, it's took just couple of seconds only.

Comment: can you declare some code ? This issue sound like `socket/hardware overflow`. (Did you sure you set smaller than ETH buffsize value ?) Another point how much socket create on large file(only one ? a bad joke)

Comment: You can investigate code on below link.
https://github.com/Codefans-fan/zklib/blob/master/zklib/zkattendance.py

Comment: @JulioElixir did you found any solution on fetching large amount of attendance data?